# Two Primefaces datatables on same page cause filtering problems

Tags: jsf, primefaces, lazy-loading, jsf-2.2, primefaces-datatable

I have a single page which includes two datatables. Their data are lazy loaded and paginated. To retrieve the rows that i need, i override the filterMap for the load() function. I pass this filterMap on the initialization of the LazyResult list. Unfortunately this causes problems with my filterMaps.

In detail:

1) On my page i got following lines to initialize both LazyLists, each for each table

```
<f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{handler.initTable1}" />
<f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{handler.initTable2}" />
```

2) In my ManageBean i am initializing the LazyList

```
public void initTable1() {
    filterMap.clear();
    filterMap.put("organization", "IBM");    
    lazyResults1= new ResultsLazyList<MyEntity1, MyBean1, MyDTO1>(
                            myBean1, filterMap);
}

public void initTable2() {
    filterMap.clear();
    filterMap.put("city", "London");    
    lazyResults2= new ResultsLazyList<MyEntity2, MyBean2, MyDTO2>(
                            myBean2, filterMap);
}
```

Inside the custom created ResultsLazyList, i am overriding the load method of LazyDataModel. Also note that i am passing as a paremeter the **filterMap** in the constructor (which used in the load method) so that i will have from the first run the results that i want.

**Problem**

Now, if i have just one table in my page, everything works fine. Adding more filters, sorting etc. Once i add the second table as shown above then the following happens.

Step 1) While the client page is loading, it calls first the **initTable1** method. The lazyResults1  is initialized with the filterMap which is set in the constructor. The load method of lazyResults1 is not triggered yet and my filterMap at this point has the values ***organization=IBM***

Step 2) While the client page is loading, it calls the **initTable2** method. This overrides the values of my filterMap  with **city=London** and initializes the lazyResults2. Note at this point the load method of lazyResults1 or lazyResults2 has not been triggered yet.

Step 3) Finally the load method **lazyResults1** is triggered, but with the filterMap containing the values set in initTable2. So in the backend, my application tries to query on **MyEntity1** with a field that exists on **MyEntity2**.

**Question**

1) Is there a way to somehow initialize lazyResults1 and trigger the load method so that my lazyResults1 is loaded with data before initTable2() is called and overrides my filterMap ?

2) I have seen some people using to ManagedBeans, each for each table, but i want to avoid this.

3) Another way is two pass 2 filterMaps in my ResultsLazyList constructor.

4) If there is another way to override the filterMap on the load method, then the way i am doing it, that would maybe solve my problem.

Comment: Any comment on the answer? Did it help? Did we miss things in your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two different tables, two different data sets... So why do you share filters between them? By reusing the same `filterMap` you're saying "I want the same filters to apply to both tables". If that's not what you want, then define separate filterMaps for each table.

> 1) Is there a way to somehow initialize lazyResults1 and trigger the load
>   method so that my lazyResults1 is loaded with data before initTable2()
>   is called and overrides my filterMap ?

These are just hacks because you're trying to have it both ways - to share and not share filters simultaneously.

Let's say the filters were exposed in UI like this: [image: Filters]
And the user changes the "Year" filter. Do you expect this change to affect some other table? Probably not. Because this set of filters belongs to this table only.

Comment: For some reason i was able to build a huge implementation in the back end but my brain stuck to solve this minor issue. Yes i could use two  different filters. I did not think of that simple thing and was thinking of more complex solutions. Thank you